# Why MySql returns an empty result

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm not a SQL expert, but I'm able to write simple query but I have a problem with a query like:

```
SELECT field 
FROM TableA 
WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM TableB)
```

I have 2 table with the same `field` name, I'm sure there at least a record in `TableA` that is not in `TableB` but MySql returns 0 results.

The 2 `field` are Varchar64 , utf8_general_ci coded and contains values like `'279960881351'`.

I'm using PhpMyAdmin to run the query and the DB is hosted.

I wonder if there is something I do not know about MySql or PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: "I'm sure there at least a record in TableA that is not in TableB" -- I think you're wrong. This simple query should work fine.

Comment: Are the `field` columns indexed? Try repairing the indexes.

Comment: The query looks just fine. Validate your assumptions once again, you may be wrong about them. Pick some concrete value and run a specialized query - with the chosen constant substituted.

Comment: Could you try this instead, 

`SELECT FIELD FROM TableA
MINUS
SELECT FIELD FROM TableB`

If this also doesn't provide you an answer your assumptions are not right my friend.

Comment: @DataWrangler MySQL doesn't have `MINUS`.

Comment: It works here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nb4PWFfMEZQ8tXoSqWb91b/0

Comment: Check that the data does not have spaces or other invisible characters in it. The query is ok.

Comment: The value I used above exists in TableA and not in TableB (at least a select does not return a record in TableB).
The column is indexed (unique) in both tables and I drop and recreate both the indexes

Comment: My link was wrong, maybe a value in table B is NULL : see [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hAcdjTPeZ961dXvnh2cWJ/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really stupid! Thank you **nfgl**! There is at least 1 null in the table!

Comment: And that's why you should use not exists rather than not in . See [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hAcdjTPeZ961dXvnh2cWJ/0)